# Convert all dates in an array to format MM/DD/YYYY javascript

Tags: javascript, date, formatting

I have an array of dates in the format :

```
dates_arr = [
    Thu Aug 13 2020 00:00:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time),
    Fri Aug 14 2020 00:00:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time),
    Sat Aug 15 2020 00:00:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time),
    Sun Aug 16 2020 00:00:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)
]
```

I would like to convert all the dates to the format `MM/DD/YYYY` and replace the array with them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I would like to convert all the dates to the format `MM/DD/YYYY` and
> replace the array.

You could do it as follows -

### Correct Code -

```js
let dates_arr = [
  'Thu Aug 13 2020 00:00:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)',
  'Fri Aug 14 2020 00:00:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)',
  'Sat Aug 15 2020 00:00:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)',
  'Sun Aug 16 2020 00:00:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)'
];
dates_arr = dates_arr.map((element) => {
  var d = new Date(element);
  return `${d.getMonth()+1}/${d.getDate()}/${d.getFullYear()}`;
})
console.log("Dates in the format MM/DD/YYYY : \n", dates_arr);
```

---

#### Explanation :

- The strings which are present in `dates_arr` are the default way in which Javascript will output the dates. We are taking each of those strings and mapping over the `dates_arr` using [`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) function and simply returning the dates in the required format. This will create a new array with strings of date in the form we need them to be.
- Firstly, I am creating a date object in the code using `new Date(element)`. The `Date()` constructor can take in date string and form date object on which we can apply various in-built methods provided by JS as given below.
- There are different methods which date provides us like

  1. [`getMonth()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getMonth) which returns the month from 0-11
  2. [`getDate()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getDate) which returns the day of the month from 1-31 and
  3. [`getFullYear()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getFullYear) which returns the year in the date.

  I have used these methods to get the date string into the desired format. There are various other methods as well which you can read more on [here](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_date_methods.asp).
- Also, if you are not aware, I am using [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) in the return statement which is just a syntactic sugar added in ES6. The return statement does the same thing as -

  ```
  return ((d.getMonth()+1) + '/' + d.getDate() + '/' + d.getFullYear())
  ```

  But using the template literals is just a more efficient way of writing such statements.

Comment: Please check again getMonth method is return one less than actual month , since it is 0 indexed

Comment: @pallavirichhariya Right, thanks for mentioning that. I have corrected it.

Answer (score 0):

```
var formattedDate = dates_arr.map(date=>dateFormat(date)); 
function dateFormat(date){
    const dateTimeFormat = new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en', { year: 'numeric', month: 'short', day: '2-digit' }) 
    const [{ value: month },,{ value: day },,{ value: year }] = dateTimeFormat .formatToParts(date )
    return `${month}/${day}/${year}`
 }
```